# Android layout error: "Resource id <res_id> is not of type STYLE (instead attr)"

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, resources, android-resources

I'm seeing an error I've never seen before w/ Android that's preventing some of my layout files from rendering in Eclipse. They render fine at runtime.

The error that shows up in the graphical layout editor (and my Error log) is:
"Resouce id 0x1010081 is not of type STYLE (instead attr)"

I've searched for resource id 0x1010081 in my R files, and I can't find it so I'm guessing maybe somehow I have a conflict with a built in Android attr. I've also verified that all of my style attributes below point to actual styles and not attr. Any help appreciated.

Here's my full layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bkg_light"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_med" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_activity"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:background="@drawable/xml_button"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_med" >

        <TextView            
            style="@style/text_large_bold_white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/activity" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_activity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_med"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView_arrow_right_start_date" 
            android:text="@string/none_selected"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_arrow_right_start_date"
            style="@style/arrow_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- kv Duration -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_duration"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout_activity"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:background="@drawable/xml_button">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_duration"
            style="@style/text_large_bold_white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/duration_lc" 
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_med"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:entries="@array/array_durations"
            android:prompt="@string/duration_lc"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" 
            android:clickable="false"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's my styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="arrow_right">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_xxlarge</item>
        <item name="android:text">@string/arrow_right</item>
    </style>

    <style name="button_blue">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_button_blue</item>
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/padding_med</item>
    </style>

    <style name="button_blue_small">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_button_blue_small</item>
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/padding_med</item>
    </style>

    <style name="button_dark">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_button_dark</item>
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/padding_med</item>
    </style>

    <style name="button_light">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_button_light</item>
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/padding_med</item>
    </style>

    <style name="button_light_small">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_small</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_button_light</item>
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/padding_small</item>
    </style>  

    <style name="text_small_gray_light">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_small</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="text_med_bold_gray_light">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_med</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray_light</item>
    </style>    

    <style name="text_large_bold_white">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_large</item>
    </style>

    <style name="text_large_bold_black">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_large</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style name="text_large_bold_gray_dark">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_large</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray_dark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="text_large_bold_gray_light">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_large</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="text_large_bold_white">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_large</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="text_large_white">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_large</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And here's my custom theme.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="Theme.P90X" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Could you attach the full error log and your styles.xml?

Comment: @JustinJasmann: styles.xml listed. The only I get is the one listed above.

Comment: Why didn't you accept the right answer ?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I also have this problem, with the same resource ID showing up. It disappears when I change `android:spinnerMode` to `"dialog"` so I suspect it's not a problem with your code.

The id in question refers to the android attribute `spinnerStyle`. See the doc for [R.attr](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html)

I found a workaround, namely replace

`android:spinnerMode="dropdown"`

with

`android:spinnerStyle="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown"`.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you!  OP should credit yours as the correct answer.

Comment: Note @android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown requires API level 11

Comment: While it does get rid of the error for me as well, I get "Error inflating class android.widget.Spinner" at runtime.

Comment: But its throwing: `04-19 15:55:44.161: E/AndroidRuntime(8799): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.widget.Spinner`

Comment: @PratikButani in view of the number of upvotes to my answer, this is likely a separate issue, or your minimum SDK level is set to something less than 11.

Comment: I got min SDK set to 15 and I still get "Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.widget.Spinner"

Comment: To those getting the InflateException, note that the attribute _name_ also changes from `spinnerMode` to `spinnerStyle`.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried changing the each style property to something like this:

```
style="?attr/text_large_bold_white"
```

Comment: The styles in my layout are custom styles defined in styles.xml. I've listed that in the posting.

Answer (score 2):

As JulianSymes says the problem is

```
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```

His solution (replace for `android:spinnerStyle="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown"`) runs on my phone but not on my tablet

My solution is more simple: DELETE THE LINE.

`spinnerMode="dropdown"` is by default, therefore it's unnecesary

Answer (score 0):

As Google points to this page for this error, and for the sake of posterity...

In my case, in a whim, I **closed and reopened eclipse** and boom the error was gone and eclipse had no problem rendering the preview.

Though I strongly believe this may not be the case for all.

If you feel you have done *everything right*, I guess, it won't hurt restarting eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by downgrading the version in Gradle:
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'