# custom spinner click doesn't work properly in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-custom-view

I use custom spinner in my android application but the spinner clickable but just on border 
of line and spinner not clickable on middle side on version greater than 3.0 and it is perfectly
 work on version less than 3.0. one more problem is when spinner populates the value that 
value is not clickable on version greater than 3.0. 

please anybody tell me why this happen.
following is the custom spinner.
[image]

my main spinner.xml

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/bldngSpnrBldng"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_selectors"
                android:prompt="@string/select_building"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

Here what happen when i open graphical Layout then I encountered exception like

> Failed to parse file ....\res\drawable\spinner_selector_selected.xml
>   Failed to parse file ....\res\drawable\spinner_selectors.xml 
>   Resouce id 0x1010081 is not of type STYLE (instead attr) Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

following is the spinner listener.

```
spinnerPhase.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) 
            new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            ........

        }
```

spinner_selector_selected.xml for border line and spinner image at corner of spinner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>


                <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/gray" />

                <corners android:radius="4dp" />

                <padding 
                    android:bottom="3dp" 
                    android:left="3dp" 
                    android:right="3dp" 
                    android:top="3dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/pressed_color"/>
            </shape>

        </item>

        <item>
            <bitmap 
                android:gravity="bottom|right" 
                android:src="@drawable/spinner_ab_default_new_theme_bs" />
        </item>
    </layer-list>

</item>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here: [Android layout error: "Resource id <res_id> is not of type STYLE (instead attr)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758734/android-layout-error-resource-id-res-id-is-not-of-type-style-instead-attr).

As mentioned there, try to replace:

```
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```

with

```
android:spinnerStyle="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown"
```