# XML file not being built (or R file not being updated)

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm starting this new question because my old question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507398/onclickhandler-not-being-called) has actually gone totally off topic because of the new discoveries that I've made with help from the commenters on that question. So here is the problem: My XML file is not being built, or the R file is not being updated. When Eclipse tries to render the XML file it comes up with this error:

Resouce id 0x1010081 is not of type STYLE (instead attr)

After some research I found that this might have something to do with the spinner style, I've tried removing the spinner completely but the app is still showing the spinner (and a button that I have removed a long time ago). I currently have no errors in the project, or any project that I'm referencing as a library. I've tried cleaning my project a dozen times but still nothing. Anyone have any clue what could be going on?

For some insight in the XML file, here is the total XML code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:geekui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#111"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#111" >

    <ViewSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/ccclan_viewSwitcher"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cclan_background_bar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/cclan_background_bar_light"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:background="#1b1b1b" >
                </View>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cclan_mainlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="100" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cclan_clanImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

                <com.timkranen.extra.RobotoButton
                    android:id="@+id/cclan_upload_button"
                    style="@style/RobotoButton"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_standard_selector"
                    android:text="Upload clan image"
                    android:textColor="#dedede" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/cclan_edittext_clanName"
                    style="@style/ClansterEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/clanster_edit_text_holo_dark"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Clan Name"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#dedede" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="100" >

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/cclan_edittext_gameName"
                        style="@style/ClansterEditText"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                        android:layout_weight="85"
                        android:background="@drawable/clanster_edit_text_holo_dark"
                        android:completionThreshold="1"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Game Name"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="#dedede" >
                    </AutoCompleteTextView>

                    <com.timkranen.extra.RobotoButton
                        android:id="@+id/cclan_addgame_button"
                        style="@style/RobotoButton"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_weight="15"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_standard_selector"
                        android:text="+"
                        android:textColor="#dedede" >
                    </com.timkranen.extra.RobotoButton>
                </LinearLayout>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/cclan_edittext_clanDescr"
                    style="@style/ClansterEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/clanster_edit_text_holo_dark"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Clan Description"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:textColor="#dedede" >
                </EditText>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

                    <com.timkranen.extra.TypefaceTextView
                        android:id="@+id/typefaceTextView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                        android:text="Open Membership: "
                        android:textColor="#dedede"
                        geekui:customTypeface="fonts/ROBOTO-THIN.TTF" />

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/memberToggle"
                        style="@style/ToggleClansterToggle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Test Text"
                        android:textOff="OFF"
                        android:textOn="ON" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/cclan_optionslayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

                    <com.timkranen.extra.RobotoButton
                        android:id="@+id/cclan_cancel_button"
                        style="@style/RobotoButton"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_left_selector"
                        android:text="Cancel"
                        android:textColor="#dedede" />

                    <com.timkranen.extra.RobotoButton
                        android:id="@+id/cclan_ok_button"
                        style="@style/RobotoButton"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_right_selector"
                        android:text="OK"
                        android:textColor="#dedede" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/wrapSelectionLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/cclan_gameLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/cclan_addGameLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible" >

                    <com.timkranen.extra.TypefaceTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Add new game"
                        android:textColor="#dedede"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        geekui:customTypeface="fonts/ROBOTO-THIN.TTF" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/cclan__addgame_title"
                        style="@style/ClansterEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/clanster_edit_text_holo_dark"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Game Title"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="#dedede" >
                    </EditText>

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/cclan_addgame_platform"
                        style="@style/ClansterEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/clanster_edit_text_holo_dark"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Platform"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="#dedede" >
                    </AutoCompleteTextView>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/cclan_addGameLayout_buttons"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <com.timkranen.extra.RobotoButton
                            android:id="@+id/cclan_addgame_cancel"
                            style="@style/RobotoButton"
                            android:layout_width="130dp"
                            android:layout_height="36dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_left_selector"
                            android:text="Cancel"
                            android:textColor="#dedede" />

                        <com.timkranen.extra.RobotoButton
                            android:id="@+id/cclan_addgame_ok"
                            style="@style/RobotoButton"
                            android:layout_width="130dp"
                            android:layout_height="36dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_right_selector"
                            android:text="OK"
                            android:textColor="#dedede" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/cclan_choosePlatformLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="invisible" >

                    <com.timkranen.extra.TypefaceTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:text="What platform do you play on?"
                        android:textColor="#dedede"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        geekui:customTypeface="fonts/ROBOTO-THIN.TTF" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/cclan_platformSpinner"
                        style="@style/Spinnerclanster"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <com.timkranen.extra.RobotoButton
                        android:id="@+id/cclan__confirm"
                        style="@style/RobotoButton"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_standard_selector"
                        android:text="Confirm"
                        android:textColor="#dedede" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cclan_choosePlatformLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <com.timkranen.extra.TypefaceTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="What platform does your clan play on?"
                    android:textColor="#dedede"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    geekui:customTypeface="fonts/ROBOTO-THIN.TTF" />



                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ViewSwitcher>
</ScrollView>
```

**Edit:** I've been trying to figure this out all day. Nothing has worked yet, I've tried creating a new project and moving the old project classes to the new project but that didn't work either. I suspect that it's in the XML file, but I don't know where.

**Edit:** My god do I feel stupid. After hours of searching and googling I've finally found the mistake. I have the same layout in the file *twice*. Double ID's and everything..

Comment: Have you try to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: @G.T. Yes multiple times, but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Is your layout up to date in the Eclipse's graphical layout?

Comment: @G.T. As mentioned above, the graphical layout doesn't render because of the error: Resouce id 0x1010081 is not of type STYLE (instead attr).

Comment: @Frank N. Stein I'm trying to replace the font name with lower case letters, let's see if it works. Edit: It didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein That didn't work either. Please keep in mind that my other fragments also use the RobotButton and TypefaceTextView like above, but still continue to work. Actually, this fragment still works but it isn't getting updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with your styles that you used in your xml. Since all of these are custom styles so it is difficult to predict if the actual problem is because of some wrong style format.

**Solution 1 -**

Try replacing each custom style to something generalized like-

```
style="?attr/text_large_bold_white"
```

**Solution 2 -**

I found a good read that says to replace your spinner mode to "dialog". You can try that.

It also suggests -

The id in question refers to the android attribute spinnerStyle. See the doc for R.attr

The workaround is to replace

```
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```

with

```
android:spinnerStyle="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown".
```

SOURCE: [android-layout-error-resource-id-res-id-is-not-of-type-style-instead-attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758734/android-layout-error-resource-id-res-id-is-not-of-type-style-instead-attr).

Comment: I've read that SO thread already, and I've tried implementing these solutions without result. Thanks for the help nonetheless.