# Resource id 0x1010081 is not of type STYLE (instead attr)

Tags: android

I'm seeing an error I've never seen before with Android that's preventing some of my layout files from rendering in Android Studio. The error that shows up in the graphical layout editor is: "`Resource id 0x1010081 is not of type STYLE (instead attr)`". I'm using Android API 17.

I tried to change from

```
 android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```

to

`android:spinnerStyle="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown"`

but it's not working

[Android layout error: "Resource id <res_id> is not of type STYLE (instead attr)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758734/android-layout-error-resource-id-res-id-is-not-of-type-style-instead-attr)

Answer (score 0):

For me this code is working `style="@android:style/Theme"` for example:

```
<Spinner

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spChooseName"
        style="@android:style/Theme"
 />
```