# Android Spinner mode: Is "Resouce id 0x1010081 is not of type STYLE (instead attr)" SAFE?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am using a spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/text"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"
    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
    android:popupBackground="@color/spinner_pop"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

The above code is showing a message **Resouce id 0x1010081 is not of type STYLE (instead attr)** but didn't mentioned as an error.

I have tried running this code, and the layout works exactly how I want it to and I am not getting any error.

I have searched, but I am not able to find a proper solution to remove the message in the graphical layout view of my xml layout.

This https://stackoverflow.com/a/16588522/2508414 doesn't work in my project.

**The question is, will my current layout create any issue in the future?**

I am running this in Eclipse Kepler, Android API Level 19.

App will be running only in API Level 16 and above.

**Edit:**
If I changed the Api Level for building the layout to 20 and above, the message goes off. The message is showing only when I am using API level 19 and below.

[image]

Comment: attach screenshot of error

Comment: @Survivor I have added the screen shot.

Comment: did you try after `android:popupBackground="@color/spinner_pop"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"` remove this line?

Comment: My requirement was spinnerMode="dropdown", so can't remove. Though removing that line only solve the message issue.

Comment: man it is not available in API level 19 so this give you error if you actualy need it then use `// Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
 
        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 
        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);` programmatically

Comment: or see this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-spinner-dropdown-example/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spBloodbanks"
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
/>
```